# Lot of operations in an API Call

Tags: angular, asp.net-core, api-design

I have an WebApp using an Asp.Net Core API + Angular app.

This app will take the data from Facebook and this data will be displayed.

I dont know what is the best thing to do, geting data from Facebook could take a long time:

- Angular will call the API which will get the data from Facebook and
  will return a big Json with all the data?  (timeout errot)
- Angular will call directly
  Facebook. On each result returns, Angular will send the data the API? (the client can begin to use too much cpu)
- Angular will call the API to get a generated Unique ID by the API. On
  the API, I have a webJob which get the data from Facebook. I have
  SignalR, on each new data from Facebook, the API send to the Angular
  App. (maybe too complex)

Or maybe there is anoter way to do it? Do you have documentation/samples which can help?

Thank you
Cedric

Comment: Please show us what you have tried

Comment: Hi, I was talking about architecture theory and not coding.
In the case where the data from an external source (in this case Facebook), what is the best thing to do? 
Do all on the client (angular)
Get and display Data from the client and then Call the Api to update data in the DB
OR Do all by API using WebJob to Call the Data Asynchronously, then send the data to the client using SignalR maybe.

Do you have an idea?